# Erro MySQL : #1265 - Dado truncado para coluna 'valor' na linha 1

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados

Boa tarde, galera.
Eu dei o seguinte comando no MySQL:

```
UPDATE procedimentos SET valor = '2.400.00' WHERE procedimentos.id_proced = 1
```

o campo valor é um *double*, já tentei com *float* e deu o mesmo erro, o que seria exatamente ?

Comment: Acredito que o problema seja formatação; não sei como está seu banco mas entendo que deveria usar `2.400,00` ou `2,400.00`

Comment: Tentei da forma que disse, mas continuou retornando o mesmo erro!

Answer (score 0):

Apenas deve ser usado um ponto, quando necessário. Também não é preciso usar plicas.

Se o valor a atualizar for 2400, pode ficar apenas:

```
UPDATE procedimentos SET valor = 2400 WHERE procedimentos.id_proced = 1
```

Se for 2,4:

```
UPDATE procedimentos SET valor = 2.4 WHERE procedimentos.id_proced = 1
```

Comment: Agora tudo faz sentido!(aquele meme)  haha'
Muito obrigado pela ajuda!
Era nisso que estava errando.

Comment: @WilliamBarreto lembre de marcar a resposta como correta ;)

Answer (score -1):

Olá, testei recentemente no banco float, decimal e real, todos apresentaram a mesma falha.
Solução: Para número zerados depois da vírgula coloque apenas 2400, caso houver números após a vírgula utilize '.' (ponto), invés de utilizar a ','(vírgula).

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).